# Automatic numbering based on already existing numbers

Tags: excel

I have an Excel document that I want to put a priority column on the row but not necessarily reflective of the row number. I want to be able to type a number in that column and it will increase all the other numbers at and below it.

For example, if I had four rows with the columns being "2, 1, 3, 4" and add a new row and want to give it a priority of '2', then it would automatically change the other rows to "3, 1, 4, 5, 2".

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you post a sample table perhaps?  What do you mean by "...with the columns being '2, 1, 3, 4'"?

Comment: I am curious about the challenge... So if I add a 2 in the new row, the old two becomes three... Any score less than a two stays the same? Everything equal or above increments? And what happens to a row with "data" but no score/rank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible if you use a VBA macro.

Is it correct to assume that this is what you mean?

Before:

```
2
1
3
4
```

After:

```
3 <--- increased by 1
1 <--- unchanged as its less than 2
4 <--- increased by 1
5 <--- increased by 1
2 <--- newly added
```

If so use the following VBA code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'I am assuming Column A is the priority column
    If (Target.Columns.Count = 1 And Target.Column = 1 And Target.Rows.Count = 1) Then
        If (IsNumeric(Target.Value)) Then
            'Make sure the value is greater than 0
            If (Target.Value > 0) Then
                'Check every existing row
                For Each cell In Target.Worksheet.UsedRange.Columns(1).Rows
                    'Skip the existing row we just added
                    If (cell.row <> Target.row) Then
                        'Increment the priority by one for all cells greater or equal to the new one
                        If (IsNumeric(cell.Value)) Then
                            If (cell.Value >= Target.Value) Then
                                cell.Value = cell.Value + 1
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next cell
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Note: This example doesn't check to see if the priority level already exists, it assumes there are no 'gaps'. You can make it more robust if you wish, by first checking to see if a priority exists, before incrementing everything by 1.